# Books on patents

Tags: book, recommendation

I am looking for some intermediate level books on patents.
I heard about a book called "[Patent It Yourself](http://amzn.to/2zUr7Ut)", has anyone read it and can you recommend it? What group is the book targeting and does it give some deeper insight? Is it country specific?

(Other suggestions are appreciated too)

Comment: Patent It Yourself targets inventors, and relates to practice before the USPTO. Where it fails, in my opinion, is by encouraging  inventors to file their own applications: which is a great way for them to waste money. It does a fair job of being a casual reference for a casually interested professional, but is not really a replacement for a proper reference book on US patent law.

Comment: I have not read the book, but I have seen comments about it in another forum. They are in line with Maca's comments. Do you have country/region orientation or not? And are you looking for an actual book or for fundamental sources (like the European Patent Convention and the Guidelines)?

Comment: Europe/germany. A book, or sth portable bigger than my phone ;)

Comment: My European go-to is Visser's The Annotated European Patent Convention. It can be a little awkward at times since it is structured around the EPC instead of logically by topic, but its commentary is typically very well written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [Patents Demystified](http://amzn.to/2xv5YkE) as a guide to patents for inventors and startups. Some folks here on Stack Exchange suggested it to me and it was just what I was looking for. Seems like the patent book that most people use.

It has a great foundation of the basics and works up to intermediate and advanced patent strategies. Unlike most patent books I found, this one is really easy to understand and has specific actionable steps and strategies for protecting inventions and maximizing protection.

It's primarily directed to the U.S. patent process, but also discusses how the foreign patent process works as well.